# Square Image - Sifr wa Wahed - Gol va Keleed

Tags: cipher, visual

Title is irrelevant, but here's a simple puzzle I made...

[image: PZL Number 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's a spoiler to say that the image contains binary text. Converting it to ASCII, you get:

> PSTBN: 0aaP9Z7a

The next step, therefore, is to

> go to [this Pastebin file](https://pastebin.com/0aaP9Z7a), which contains the following text:
>
>  `vasmc ik ek awwjoyi rh hdc rgx xu omkv s vfgw ej gmfasux kc uprwe cfij tiwri`

The key to decrypting this is also in the image:

> The repeating images of the key and rose hint that this is a Vigenere cipher with the key "ROSE".

Decrypting it results in what I presume is the final message:

> `email us at message at pzl dot gg with a rose as subject to claim your prize`
>
>  As a note to OP: [offering off-site rewards for on-site activity is discouraged here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6261/31839), so I'm reluctant to actually do that, especially without knowing what the prize is. The fact that I've posted the decrypted message here should be proof enough that I've solved it.

As a final note, "Sifr wa Wahed" apparently translates to "zero and one".

Comment: Ah ya sniped me!

Comment: @ZanyG Don't worry, I know the feeling. Happened to me plenty of times!

Comment: Well, that was quick! Yes, `Sift wa Wahed` means zero and one in Arabic, and `Gol va Keleed` means `Rose and Keys` in Persian. Didn't know what to do with the title. I had this puzzle posted on Instagram for a while just to see how Instagram and the puzzle audience is, but meh. This place is always more fun :) But the puzzles I made are too simple for y'all!